# How to test a WKWebView using RxWebKit?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rxtest

I'm trying to write some tests for my application, that uses rxSwift. In particular, I'd like to test, writing unit tests, a webview. I'm using RxWebKit to get observables over some properties like navigationCompleted or NavigationFailed and so on.
For example: `webView.rx.didFailNavigation.asDriver()`. These observables are given as input to my viewModel.
But i'm not sure how to write these tests to simulate, for example, a failed navigation and so an emission of this kind of observable.
In the specific case, i want to simulate a `Driver<(webView: WKWebView, navigation: WKNavigation, error: Error)>` (that is the same type of the one associated to `webView.rx.didFailNavigation.asDriver()`).
I understood that to simulate the emission i need to create a scheduler and call the `createHotObservable` method, but what have I to pass to `Recorderd.next(150, element)` as element in the specific case to simulate the fail of the webview?
can someone give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too general question so I'll give a more general answer:

You need to look into testing with RxSwift, either using:

1. RxTest: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/UnitTests.md

for example:

```
func testElementsEmitted() {
    let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)

    let xs = scheduler.createHotObservable([
        .next(210, "RxSwift"),
        .next(220, "is"),
        .next(230, "pretty"),
        .next(240, "awesome")
    ])

    let res = scheduler.start { xs.asObservable() }

    XCTAssertRecordedElements(res.events, ["RxSwift", "is", "pretty", "awesome"])
}
```

2. or you can use RxBlocking: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxBlocking

For example, here's a good point to start:

http://rx-marin.com/post/rxblocking-part1/

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added some details to address better my problem.

Comment: If you want to pass an error, then do it as .error() the same way you would emit a next element in sequence.